# What calls the initialize method in application CPP file in veins?

Tags: omnet++, veins

```
void myAPP::initialize(int stage) {
    ....
}
```

I am trying to understand what calls? I have done the tictoc tutorial but the initialize method in there does not have int stage as a parameter. Can someone shine some light?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multi-stage initialization (i.e. `initialize` with `stage` parameter) is used by the simulation environment if a module contains [redefined](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/#sec:simple-modules:multi-stage-init) `numInitStages()` method.

**Example 1:**
No redefinition `numInitStages()` in the class. 
The simulation environment calls method:

- `initialize()`

**Example 2:**
The class contains:

```
int numInitStages() const { return 3; }
void initialize(int stage);
```

The simulation environment calls methods:

- `initialize(0)`
- `initialize(1)`
- `initialize(2)`

`TicToc` examples don't have `numInitStages()` so `initialize()` without parameters is called.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. and in the latter case, where's initialize(0) --(2) is invoked?

Comment: In the second example a class contains `initialize(int stage)` method. During preparing of a network the simulation environment will call `initialize(0)`, then `initialize (1)` and so on. Of course inside `initialize (int stage)` the current stage should be recognized.

Comment: Multi-stage initialization is used to resolve any dependencies between modules. You can initialize parts of a module in different stages to make sure parts of other modules which the current part in your module depends on are already created/initiliazed.